# VBScript won't save Excel file when invoked via Java

Tags: java, excel, vbscript

As part of a Java Application I'm building there is a requirement to open two excel files, copy data from file A to file B, save file B with a new name, and then close both files. Currently I have a VBScript that accomplishes this task, which java invokes via:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec("cscript " + pathtovbscript);
```

When this script is invoked via the Java program, it seems to run fine, and doesn't throw any errors, but when I go to the target directory to search for the resulting Excel file, it isn't there. I know it is opening excel, because I can see it appear if I'm watching the task manager as the program executes.

Finally, if I invoke the script via the command line manually, everything works fine, and the new file is created.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

VBScript Below:

```
Dim destworkbook
Dim excel
Dim currsave
Dim sourceexcellist

sourcepath = path1
destpath = path2
sourcetab = tabname1
desttab = tabname2
savepath = savepathname

desttablist = Split(desttab, ",")
sourcelist = Split(sourcepath, ",")
sourcetablist = Split(sourcetab, ",")
destlist = Split(destpath, ",")
savelist = Split(savepath, ",")

Wscript.Echo "Number of Sources: " + Cstr(UBound(sourcelist)+1)

If UBound(desttablist) = UBound(sourcelist) And UBound(sourcelist) =    UBound(sourcetablist) And UBound(sourcetablist) = UBound(destlist) Then
WScript.Echo "Arguments Equal"

Else
Wscript.Echo "Error: Arguments Invalid"
Wscript.Echo "Dest Tabs: " + Cstr(UBound(desttablist)) 
Wscript.Echo "Source Tabs: " + Cstr(UBound(sourcetablist)) 
Wscript.Echo "Sources: " + Cstr(UBound(sourcelist))
Wscript.Echo "Destinations: " + Cstr(UBound(destlist)) 
Wscript.Quit
End If
i=0
j=0
Set excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
For Each source in sourcelist
Wscript.Echo "Opening Excel"
If i>0 Then
lastdest = destlist(i-1)
Wscript.Echo "Last Destination file is " + lastdest
End If
Wscript.Echo "Creating Excel Object"


Wscript.Echo "Opening Workbook Located at " + sourcelist(i)
Set sourceWorkbook = excel.Application.Workbooks.Open(sourcelist(i))

excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
excel.Application.Visible = False
Wscript.Echo "Opening Workbook Located at " + destlist(i)
If lastdest <> destlist(i) Then
Wscript.Echo "Last Template Not Equal To Current Template"
destWorkbook.close
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Wscript.Echo "No Active Excel"
Err.Clear
End If
Set destWorkbook = excel.Application.Workbooks.Open(destlist(i))
currsave = savelist(j)
Wscript.Echo "Current Save Path is " + currsave
j=j+1
End If
Wscript.Echo "Copying Range in " + sourcetablist(i)
sourceWorkbook.Sheets(sourcetablist(i)).UsedRange.Copy
Wscript.Echo "Activating Destination Range in " +desttablist(i)
destWorkbook.Sheets(desttablist(i)).Activate
destWorkbook.Sheets(desttablist(i)).Range("A1").Select
Wscript.Echo "Pasting data"
destWorkbook.Sheets(desttablist(i)).Paste
sourceWorkbook.close
    Wscript.Echo "Saving results at " + currsave
    destWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=currsave
    Wscript.Echo "Quitting Source File at " + sourcelist(i)
    excel.Application.Workbooks.Activate(sourcelist(i))
    sourceWorkbook.Activate
    excel.Application.Quit
    sourceexcellist(i) = sourceExcel
    i=i+1
    Next
    For Each w in excel.Application.Workbooks
        Wscript.Echo "Closing Workbook"
        w.close
        Next
        Wscript.Echo "Closing Excel"
        excel.Application.quit
```

Comment: Sure it's not just putting it in a different folder?

Comment: You need to show your VBScript code, since your Java code is obviously working just fine.

Comment: yep, I know it isn't putting it in a different folder, because when I run it manually the file is created where I expect. VBScript code below: